# eliminar valores de una columna de un dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Cómo elimino los valores que no tienen 4 dígitos de la columna años de un dataframe?

`df['Year'] = df['Year'].astype(str)`

`df['Year'] = df['Year'].str.replace(r'')`

Después cómo selecciono un rango de años ?,podría usar:

`df['Year'[1925,1975]]`

Answer (score 0):

Aunque existen varias formas de hacerlo, un ejemplo para lograr los filtrados de tu pregunta, serían:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'year': [1990, 1991, 1992, 2019, 2017, 123], 'colors': ['red', 'white', 'blue','pink','black','green']})
print ('----- data frame inicial-----')
print (df)
```

Esta es una forma de filtrar, para un rango de valores en la columna `year`:

```
df1 = df[(df['year'] > 1991) & (df['year'] < 2019)]
print ('----- data frame filtrado rangos de años-----')
print (df1)
```

Aquí un ejemplo para asignar `NaN` a los años menores a 1000 (que son los que tienen menos de 4 cifras):

```
df.loc[df['year'] < 1000] = None
print ('----- data frame quitando 3 cifras-----')
print (df)
```